# Better way to get highest key in treemap?

Tags: java, time-complexity, treemap

**Way1:**

```
TreeMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
int highestKey = map.lastKey();
```

**Source Code of TreeMap.lastKey() from JDK:**

```
 Entry<K,V> p = root;
        if (p != null)
            while (p.right != null)
                p = p.right;
        return p;
```

**Way2:**

```
TreeMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
Object[] keys = map.keySet().toArray();
int highestKey = keys[keys.length - 1]
```

When you look into the implementation of the lastKey() we see that we have a while  loop. I think time complexity for this is O(n).

This makes me think that Way2 is better or efficient way to implement in terms of time complexity. Is my understanding correct ? Which is the better way to use.

Comment: Your way2 will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when there is no item in map.

Comment: Running down the tree to a leaf node is O(log n) because that's the height of a (balanced) tree.

Answer (score 2):

I think you got it wrong, the JDK implementation of `lastKey()` has a time complexity of O(logn) and not O(n) and no extra space complexity. It is a red-black tree(i.e., balanced).

And in the `Way 2` to mentioned you are getting all the keys using `keyset().toArray()` which is O(n), also storing those in an `object []` has extra space complexity of O(n) too.

With these, the JDK implementation has a much better time and space complexity.

Comment: I think the time complexity for keySet() is O(1).
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850802/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-java-util-hashmap-class-keyset-method

Comment: @adithyadn I know keySet() is O(1) for a plain `Hashmap`. But I doubt it is same for `TreeMap` as well. Will cross check the implementation and update.

Comment: But then, one thing to note is you are calling `map.keySet().toArray()`. This is AbstractCollection.java and it has O(n) complexity, which makes finally `Way2:` to be `O(n)`. Isn't it?.Please check. Regardless, it is good idea to verify `treeMap.keySet()`.

Comment: Also, Since Set doesn't guarantee the iteration ordering of elements, assuming the last element of the `Object[] keys`would be the highest element may not be safe as well. Good question, upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [binary max-heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap), the "largest" element will always be the root node of the tree and you can get it in O(1) time.

I don't think there is Java implementation of it, though, so you'd have to code it yourself.

Alternatively, provide the TreeMap a custom Comparator to flip the ordering of the elements, so the data you want is at the root, again making it O(1) lookup for the "largest" element.