# How to retrieve the key with a maximum value in a TreeMap in Java?

Tags: java, treemap

I have a tree map declared as follows:

```
TreeMap<Integer, Integer> tree = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

How do I retrieve the key with the maximum value. Is there an O(1) way of achieving this. I know that maximum and minimum keys can be retrieved from a TreeMap in O(1) time as follows:

```
int maxKey = tree.lastEntry().getKey();
int minKey = tree.firstEntry().getKey();
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Use the values as your key (if the values are distinct) in your TreeMap and then do as you want!

Comment: Minimum and maximum keys can be retrieved in O(1) in a TreeMap?  Really?  How?

Comment: @WasiAhmad The values are not distinct in the TreeMap

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the question, max and min keys can be retrieved from the TreeMap in O(1). This is the advantage over using a data structure like HashMap or HashSet.

Comment: @JoeC looking up any value including the min/max is O(log N) but retrieving what it is, is O(1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The collection is not sorted by value so the only way is brute force O(n) unless there is another collection with say the reverse map available.

```
Map<Integer, Integer>map = new TreeMap<>();
int max = map.values().stream().max(Integer::compare).get();
```

Comment: I thought there was a way of doing this in O(1). Thanks anyways.

Comment: @SpiderMan You need another TreeMap/TreeSet of the values to do that.

Comment: But when using a second TreeMap, be careful there aren't duplicates in the values... you will lose keys.

Comment: @DrewWills this is only a problem when you remove a value. If the values are the same maximum value it doesn't matter but when you remove a value, you need to know if it is the last occurrence of that value or not.

Answer (score 2):

O(1) complexity is not possible with TreeMap. you need to create one more map which uses value of first map as keys. or use [BiMap](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/12/google-guava-bimaps.html)

```
public TreeBiMap implements Map {
   private Map<Integer, Integer> map;
   private Map<Integer, Integer> reverseMap;
   public TreeBiMap() {
     map = new TreeMap<>();
     reverseMap = new TreeMap<>();
   }

   public void put(Integer key, Integer value) {
      map.put(key, value);
      reverseMap.put(value, key);
   }

   public Integer getMaxValue() {
      return reverseMap.lastEntry().getKey()
   }

}
```

Comment: An example implementation or links would be useful. Thanks @MukeshKumar

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you basically have to iterator each map entry and find the entry with the largest value.

---

Note that in your post you made a mistake.

> I know that maximum and minimum keys can be retrieved from a TreeMap
> in O(1) time as follows:

```
int maxKey = tree.lastEntry().getKey();
int minKey = tree.firstEntry().getKey();
```

I think the time complexity should be `O(lgn)`.

The source code of `getLastEntry`:

```
/**
     * Returns the last Entry in the TreeMap (according to the TreeMap's
     * key-sort function).  Returns null if the TreeMap is empty.
     */
    final Entry<K,V> getLastEntry() {
        Entry<K,V> p = root;
        if (p != null)
            while (p.right != null)
                p = p.right;
        return p;
    }
```

Also refer to [this post in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35216414/better-way-to-get-highest-key-in-treemap)

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @PeterLawrey answers the question fair enough. If you are looking for a simpler implementation, here it is:

```
TreeMap<Integer, Integer> tree = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
// populate the tree with values
Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> maxEntry = null;
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : tree.entrySet()){
   if(maxEntry == null || entry.getValue().compareTo(maxEntry.getValue()) > 0)
      maxEntry = entry;
}

System.out.println("The key with maximum value is : " + maxEntry.getKey());
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you depend on using a TreeMap/do you fill it yourself? I ran into a similar situation and extended the TreeMap by the missing functionality:

```
public class TreeMapInteger<T> extends TreeMap<Integer,T> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1193822925120665963L;

    private int minKey = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    private int maxKey = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    @Override
    public T put(Integer key, T value) {

        if(key > maxKey) {
            maxKey = key;
        }

        if(key < minKey) {
            minKey = key;
        }

        return super.put(key, value);

    }

    public int getMaxKey() {
        return maxKey;
    }

    public int getMinKey() {
        return minKey;
    }

}
```

This won't decrease the complexity but depending on when and how your Map is filled having the values prepared for you when you need them might be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

As TreeMap in java implement a Red-Black tree(A self-balancing binary search tree). As its a balanced binary search tree in core, max key and min key can in accessed in O(log n) time.

```
max = map.lastEntry().getKey();
min = map.firstEntry().getKey();
```